# Kentico 13 - Automatically detect visitor culture not working

Tags: kentico, kentico-13

I have a site where the default culture is German but I also have an English culture assigned to the site and the site is set up to automatically detect visitor culture:

[image: culture assignment]

[image: Url Settings]

Both mydomain.com and mydomain.com/en work as expected

However, from reading the documentation, going to mydomain.com should automatically send me to mydomain.com/en as my browser is using english and sends the value of "en-US" in the Accept-Language header.

I've restarted the app pool, cleared browser storage for the site, tried different browsers in standard mode and incognito mode.

I'm using v13.0.124

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto detection of language is based on the browsers language settings and not the physical location or IP address of the person visiting the site.  My suggestion is to

1. install the German language pack to your browser,
2. set that language as the primary/default language,
3. clear your cookies and
4. try the site again in a private window.

Comment: Hi Brendan, I have the opposite issue. My browser is in English but the site serves up the German version instead of auto redirecting me to /en

Comment: Is your browser language the same code as your site's English version?  For example, en-US is not the same as en-UK even though it may still be English, it's not.   Secondly, had you navigated to the /en version of your site prior?  If so, then it stores that as a cookie and by default will automatically load that version of the site.  The "auto-detection" is really only good for visitors who have NEVER visited your site before.   My suggestion is to try on a browser on a server, a browser that's never been to the site before or clear all your history, cookies and such and try again.

Comment: Interesting, on closer inspection I see my browser accepts multiple languages (I assume the higher the q value the more preference but Kentico just checks a matching value). I'll get my hands on someone with an exclusively en-US machine/environment.

Another interesting one is the only cookie is see set is the BNI_persistence cookie so need to look into that too.

Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: Correct, the order of the languages defines the priority of the language.  So if English is higher than German, the auto-detection will see English as the primary browser language.

Comment: My browser gives english a higher q value and after clearing cookies, data etc I still do not get redirected to the /en version. I thought because Kentico spots that de is an accepted language and de is the default culture it just serves up de. So I tried using postman instead and set accept-language to only be english but still no joy. I'll have to look deeper, there may be something in my middleware causing issues.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: Not only do you have to have DE flagged as default, it also needs to be at the top of the list in your list of languages for your browser.  That's the only way you'll get DE to "auto-detect" (unless you remove EN all together from your browser)

Comment: In my case DE is the default culture in Kentico but EN is the top priority culture in my browser but Kentico still serves up the DE culture. When I tried it with postman and set EN as the only browser language it still serves up DE.